# Inverse of Perl regex X modifier

Tags: php, regex, perl, spam-prevention

I would like to use a Perl regular expression to match strings like this:

```
spaM
s p a m
sp Am
S   p a   m
```

Looking at Perl's `x` modifier, I should be able to do this:

```
<?php
echo preg_match('#spam#ix', 's p a   m');
?>
```

But this prints out 0 (false). The `x` modifier actually ignores whitespace on the regex, not the string being analyzed. How would I do it the other way around? That is, ignore whitespace on the string being analyzed rather than my regex? I'm aware there are multi-step ways to do this, such as first stripping all white space from the string, but I wanted to know if there was a powerful one-step regex solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#x` modifier works the other way around. It allows to use extraneous whitespace in the regex, which is ignored for searching:

```
preg_match('# s p a m #ix')
```

Will only ever match "spam".

What you need to do in order to find arbitrary whitespace with your regex is to inject `\s*` between any letters:

```
preg_match('# S \s* P \s* A \s* M #ix', 's p a   m');
```

You can automate/simplify that a bit, by converting words into an appropriate regex with intermixed `\s*` using:

```
$regex = join('\s*', str_split("spam", 1));
preg_match("#$regex#ix", "s p a m");
```

Comment: They should invent something to do this all in the regex. In our day and age, a good chunk of web development is fighting spam.

Comment: @JoJo, Maintaining a list of spam terms and transformations is not the job of a regex engine, but that of a module.

Comment: @JoJo, It may be easier to remove the spaces from the string rather than accommodating for them in the pattern.

Comment: @ikegami: That's true. It's also what mod_security does (normalizing/decoding first, then probing). However depends on the context. If you also want to check for word boundaries (not certain in this case), then space removal might be detrimental. (Wrote a PHP port of spamassassing once. There's a variety of pros and cons here.)

Answer (score 7):

Truthfully, I think you are better off stripping the whitespace then matching. Since this is what you mean to do, your code will be clearer than finding a magic regex, or injecting whitspace patterns between letters.

The Perl for this would then look something like.

```
my $string = "S   p A m";
(my $string_no_ws = $string) =~ s/\s//g;
if ($string_no_ws =~ /spam/i) {
  #do something
}
```

actually you can do the test without a regex if you want to, using [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html):

```
my $string = "S   p A m";
(my $lc_string_no_ws = lc $string) =~ s/\s//g;
if (index($lc_string_no_ws, 'spam') >= 0) {
  #do something
}
```

Comment: This is both cleaner and more efficient than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

the `/x` modifying for regex in perl refers to the regex construct and not to what is being matched. To match the values you have you want

```
/s\s*p\s*a\s*m\s*/i
```

if order matters for the word spam, and if it doesn't then something like

```
/[spam \t\n\r]+/
```

would suffice

Comment: "maps", "spa", "sap", and so on really shouldn't be considered to be the same word as "spam"!

Comment: Well no, they aren't hence the distinction of "order not mattering"

Comment: You said "*if* order matters" (emphasis mine). I pointed out that order *does* matter.